# JAVA RegEx on _ delimited string

Tags: java, regex

OK, I need a RegEx that traps the first word up to underscore character but then capture the next words that may have a underscore character. So, here is a group and the expected result:

```
gear_Armor_Blessed_Robes = "gear", "Armor" and "Blessed_Robes"
gear_Armor_Chain_Coif = "gear", "Armor" and "Chain_Coif"
gear_Armor_Chain_Hauberk = "gear", "Armor" and "Chain_Hauberk"
gear_Armor_Chain_Shirt = "gear", "Armor" and "Chain_Shirt"
gear_Armor_Chain_Leggings = "gear", "Armor" and "Chain_Leggings"
```

Comment: I have to use RegEx due to the fact it is a program that uses JAVA RegEx but I do not have access to the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use a regex for this, just use `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
String s = "Armor_Blessed_Robes";
int idx = s.indexOf("_");
System.out.println(s.substring(0, idx)); // Armor
System.out.println(s.substring(idx + 1)); // Blessed_Robes
```

With regex, you'd have to use the following, which is a tad more complicated and harder to read:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^_]+)_(.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  String first = m.group(1);  // Armor
  String second = m.group(2); // Blessed_Robes
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the original post, but this is the closest to what I need.

Comment: @NeoFax: Do the new strings always start with `gear_`? If so, you can easily change the above regex to `"gear_([^_]+)_(.+)"`.

Comment: Yes they do.  The script looks for only the JSON value that begins with gear.  Perfect!  Your code in your comment works great!  Thanks!

Comment: @NeoFax I don't quite understand why you'd pick this answer when it requires more work. `s.split("_", 2)` will return an array of `String` `{ "gear", "Armor", "Blessed_Robes" }`

Comment: The reason I chose this one is that I do not have access to s.split.  It needs to be RegEx only and Joao's code snippet worked perfectly with the "gear_([^_]+)_(.+)"

Answer (score 4):

You can split along `_`, limiting the number of splits to 3:

```
assert Arrays.equals("gear_Armor_Blessed_Robes".split("_", 3),
    new String[] { "gear", "Armor", "Blessed_Robes" });
```

It should give you a `String[]` that contains the 3 `String`s as specified in your question.

Comment: @veer: Thanks for modifying my code (since the OP changes the question), but please test your code before modifying the code (not that I'm any better).