# Java regex for # delimited record

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have text rows of following format. It is a record of fixed segments of upto 6 columns delimited by comma and which can repeat one or more times. The segment separation is delimited by #

Example:
single record in row:

```
AA,123,SRC,DES,X,ABCD123
```

two records in row:

```
AA,123,SRC,DES,X,ABCD123#AB,234,SRC,DES,X,ABCD234
```

I'm looking for build reg-ex for this structure pattern. So far I've build partial reg-ex based on my requirements (which will be case-insensitive).

```
regexp ="^([a-z]{2},[a-z0-9]{1,5},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{1}(,[a-z0-9]{1,25})?)+$"
```

What I'm struggling with is finding the repeated segments. Here is a link that has some delimiter expression information but I'm unable to incorporate it. Can someone help me understand?

[JAVA RegEx on _ delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127328/java-regex-on-delimited-string)

Comment: Why are you using `^` and `$` in your regex?

Comment: to define input string boundaries

Comment: And what exactly your regex should be able to match with such boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that your matches are constrained by the line or # delimiters you can use `(^|(?<=#))` at the start to match start of line or ensure it is preceded by #,  and `($|(?=#))` at the end to match end of line or ensure it is followed by #

Here's the full regex

```
(?mi)(^|(?<=#))([a-z]{2},[a-z0-9]{1,5},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{1}(,[a-z0-9]{1,25})?)($|(?=#))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI6nH1/1) for results and further explanation

You can also specify some of the groups as non-capturing with `(?:` so that you only get one match for each record e.g.

```
(?mi)(?:^|(?<=#))([a-z]{2},[a-z0-9]{1,5},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{1}(?:,[a-z0-9]{1,25})?)(?:$|(?=#))
```

See updated [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI6nH1/2)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion regex's are overused. Here's what I would do, making use of the Guava library.  It's pretty simple to do this without guava as well, just a bit more work.

```
String data = readInData();
for(String row : Splitter.on("#").split(data)){
  List<String> columns = ImmutableList.copyOf(Splitter.on(",").split(row));
  //now you can process these columns however you want!
}
```

Comment: Why overused? You can do same with simple `for(String row : data.split("#")){String[] columns = row.split(","); /*rest of code*/}`. IMO `data.split("#")` looks simpler than `Splitter.on("#").split(data)`.

Comment: using .split() seems fine actually. I just don't like the massive regex expression that is trying to do everything without a loop. The Guava Splitter has the benefit of skipping empty values or ignoring whitespace if you want to.

Comment: I'm really constrained to use only reg-ex solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is the anchors that should be left out. They prevent the regex from matching the string twice. Also, no idea if you are using the ignorecase flag, I am adding an inline option. Here is what works:

```
 regexp ="(?i)([a-z]{2},[a-z0-9]{1,5},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{3},[a-z]{1}(,[a-z0-9]{1,25})?)+";
```